# Nested frames in Silverlight LOB application

Tags: silverlight, navigation

I wonder if anybody can point me out to the best way of handling the following scenario:

I am developing a silverlight LOB application that has a few main areas (Home, About, Area1, Area2, ...), that are loaded within a frame on the mainPage.

Depending on the area the users are in I load a page with different menu and user interaction controls.

Each of this areas has a frame (let's call it subframe) that loads different pages (Screen1, Screen2, ...) depending on what the user wants to view.

All works fine and I can load whatever page I want within the subframe by using hyperlinks and targeting it.

Now, my issue is that I need to support direct access to this screens via address bar or direct linking (email...).

i.e.: http://www.mydomain.com/myapp/app.aspx#/Area1/Screen1?id=12345

On this scenario, what I would like to accomplish was for my frame to load the Area1 view and the Area1 view has a subframe that would load Screen 1 view passing it the query string.

Thanks for your help.

Hugo Fonseca

Comment: I would advise you against nestling frames. It adds complexity to your app and its not worthwhile. It's best to keep separate things as pages when you can and have a tabcontrol inside when you need to. You can pass a parameter in the query string and let the page select the right tabitem.

Comment: Arthur, I would agree with you in principle, but in my scenario some of the areas have more than a dozen possible screens and some of them can be opened more than once, since I am supporting a customized form of history that allows the user to be editing an object (let's say a contact) get a phone call, check out something on another contact and come back to finishing editing the first contact.